# Convergent subsequence in $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

If $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $L^1(\Omega)$, we know that if the BV($f_n$) is uniformly bounded then there exists a subsequence which converges in $L^1$ norm(Because BV is embedding in $L^1$ is compact).

Is there any criteria other than uniform BV bound which ensures the existence of subsequence which converges in $L^1$

Comment: check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_theorem for $p=1$